# How to fix "Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): RUBY_VERSION."

Tags: ruby

Today i just want to setup a jekyll Blog on my Mac, and  have already install ruby 2.3.0, but when make '$ jekyll serve', it's error. and show this in terminal:

**Error information:**

```
Unknown ruby interpreter version (do not know how to handle): RUBY_VERSION.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Coincidentally today I am also trying to setup Jekyll and am seeing the same problem. I am using RVM and it otherwise works fine (running multiple Rails dev sites locally). When I run `env | grep 'RUBY'` I get:

```
$ env | grep 'RUBY'
MY_RUBY_HOME=/Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247
RUBY_VERSION=ruby-2.0.0-p247
```

However, I just continued and ran `bundle install`, then `bundle exec jekyll serve` and the site booted up without issue.

Answer (score 16):

So it looks like

```bash
bundle exec jekyll new
```

will create the a Gemfile with the line

```rb
ruby RUBY_VERSION
```

I believe you'll want to edit that file to be e.g.

```rb
ruby '2.1.1'
```

Comment: hmmm. is that a jekyll bug or what? in my case I use rvm, is that an interoperability issue between jekyll and rvm?

Comment: @matanster I guess (from the other answers in this thread) that bundler actually knows how to get the ruby version from the environment variable. But yes, it appears that rvm magic must try to parse the Gemfile and chokes on that. rvm is so ambitious! It's probably better to use a ```.ruby-version``` file instead, since that seems to be used in rvm, rbenv, and chruby. See discussion in [Is It A Bad Practice to List Ruby Version in Both Gemfile and .ruby-version Dotfile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32934651/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-list-ruby-version-in-both-gemfile-and-ruby-version-dotf)

Comment: Thank you @TKH.  I was overthinking the issue.  I followed Jason's diagnostic step and could see Ruby was installed properly.  Once I modified the gem file, the nasty message was gone.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Seems like there is no variable *RUBY_VERSION* in your env.

Try in your shell: `env | grep 'RUBY'`

Output should be like this:
`RUBY_VERSION=ruby-2.3.0`

If you don't see anything, you need to reinstall ruby.

Use RVM or other ruby version manager. [Here is a good manual](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/)

Comment: thanks for your help , i'm sure i have installed ruby , also output `RUBY_VERSION=ruby-2.3.0` . Does there have wrong with it's location or other wrong?

Comment: I get this even when I am using `rvm`, so `rvm` alone is not enough to resolve it

Answer (score 3):

I used to have `ruby '~> 2.6.3'` in Gemfile and got same warning.
I changed it to ruby '2.6.3' and it fixed it.

Comment: While that certainly works, it is no no longer stating that you would prefer to run with the most current Ruby from the 2.6 minor version.

Answer (score 1):

First, make a app using

```
npx react-native init sample-project
```

Then go to the `ios` folder

```
cd ios 
run pod install
```

After running `pods install`, you’ll see

```
Generating Pods project
Setting REACT_NATIVE build settings
Setting CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD to c++17 on /Users/mac/sample/ios/sample.xcodeproj
```

Your app should work fine, so now just run

```
run yarn ios
```

or

```
npm run ios
```

Comment: Worked for me, thanks.

Comment: The question is about Jekyll not React Native

Answer (score 1):

1. First you need to check what is your ruby version, to check the ruby version run the command:

   "ruby -v"
2. Open the file "Gemfile"
3. Replace the ruby version with your ruby version
4. Run the command

   "bundle update"
   Now your app works fine

Comment: Worked for me, thanks.

Comment: That's not a global solution and might have to replace many files